# How to extract numerical value from. Line in shell

Tags: regex, shell

I have line like new line

Found 1 modem:

```
 /Org/freedesktop/ModeManager1/Modem/12 [Generic] MBIM [8087:0911]
```

I wanted to extract only numeric value  after Modem/ & till the numeric values end & space comes from grep command in shell

Comment: What is the desired results?

Comment: Number just after slash

Comment: Use `grep -oP "(?<=/Modem/)[0-9]+"`

Comment: As **Wiktor** said, you can use `grep` but with **Perl** feature. like: `grep -oP '\d+(?= )'`

Comment: So, what text processing tool can you use? Please update the question and let know via a comment using `@`+username.

Answer (score 1):

if you want just numeric value after Modem/, you can use this:

```
(?=Modem\/(\d+)\s)
```

Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/cEelYj/1)

For a number that is between slash and space, use this one:

```
(?=\/(\d+)\s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this,

```
(?=Modem\/([0-9]+)\s)
```

Try it on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cEelYj/2)

Comment: /Org/freedesktop/ModeManager1/Modem/12 [Generic] MBIM [8087:0911]
Can u help me out store the numeric values after modem slash

Answer (score 0):

You may use `grep` with an `o` (to extract the matched text) and `P` (to enable using PCRE patterns with lookarounds) options:

```
echo "/Org/freedesktop/ModeManager1/Modem/12 [Generic] MBIM [8087:0911]" | \
      grep -oP "(?<=/Modem/)[0-9]+"
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/WNdmRV).

The pattern matches

- `(?<=/Modem/)` - a place in string that is preceded with `/Modem/` (as the `(?<=...)` is a positive lookbehind that only checks if the pattern matches the text without placing that text into the returned match value)
- `[0-9]+` - 1 or more digits.

Comment: -p option is not compiled into --disable-perl-regex
Can u help out

Comment: @user8032404: If you use it under  MinGW "-P" option might not be available. Then, you cannot use grep here. Try with `awk` - `echo $s | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "/Modem/| " } { print $2 }'` - see [this demo](http://ideone.com/ZZ2Dzb).

Comment: Cool, so what *can* you use there?

Comment: I am having command like mmcli - L which give output​ like 

/org/freedesktop/ModemManager/Modem/12 [Generic] MBIM [8087:0911]

Comment: But it does not let you run any extraction on the text. Can you use perl, awk, sed? Can you use plain Bash? Try `echo $s | sed 's!.*/Modem/\([0-9]*\) .*!\1!'`

Comment: For that I tried like $s = mmcli -L Giving bash :=: command not found

Comment: I think all mmcli history will be some log from there we can

Comment: Docs say there is bash pre-installed. See [this demo](http://ideone.com/OLdjtX) with Bash as the third option.